# Filtering IQueryable<T> returns wrong result

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have just run into quite surprising problem.

The case is simple: return all entities that are currently active, which means: filter all result returned by `GetAll()` method according to their Boolean Active property

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAllActive()
{
      return implementation.GetAll().Where(a => ((IDeactivable)a).Active);  
}
```

where `GetAll()` method of implementation object is defined as:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll();
```

The problem is, that `GetAllActive()` returns all the records, regardless of value of their Active property, just like there is no Where clause.

What could be the reason for it?

**Note:** The code is simplified, `T` type is checked to implement the `IDeactivable` interface. Also no exception is thrown during at runtime.

**Edit:** IQueryable returned by implementation object comes from NHibernate

**Edit2:** I have used following code to check the actual values for the entities (besides using VS Debugger):

```
foreach (var a in active) {              //active -> filtered IQueryable before return
        _logger.Warn(a.Id);
        _logger.Warn(((IDeactivable)a).Active);
}
```

the result was:

```
11/30/2011 18:10:00 WARN xxx.Repository`1.GetAllActive: 70db43fa-2361-4c1f-a8e5-9fab012b5a2b
11/30/2011 18:10:01 WARN xxx.Repository`1.GetAllActive: False
11/30/2011 18:10:02 WARN xxx.Repository`1.GetAllActive: 5493c9bb-ec6e-4690-b5d6-9fab012b5b16
11/30/2011 18:10:02 WARN xxx.Repository`1.GetAllActive: True
```

Comment: To troubleshoot it, you'll have to prove that `((IDeactivable)someRecord).Active` is actually returning `false` when it is supposed to.  Seems as if it's always returning `true`.

Comment: Are you really really really sure that the error doesn't like inside some of the code you have removed? At a glance that looks like it will do what you want. My suspicion is that the problem lies somewhere in the code that you have cut out in your simplification or have you proved that the above does actually fail too? As others might say can you provide a small yet complete program that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Anything in your `Where` predicate is relevant. Don't simplify this part.

Comment: Also for debugging try `implementation.GetAll().ToEnumerable().Where(...` which will do the filtering in .net instead of translating it.

Comment: This is just a SWAG, but try `.Where(a => ((IDeactivable)a).Active) == true)` and `.Where(a => ((IDeactivable)a).Active).Equals(true))`

Comment: I have tried several ways of writing Where already, even though most of them seem to do the same job, result is the same.

HOWEVER, I have tried what CodeInChaos had proposed and IT DOES WORK. But what is the actual reason of it, and what is the effect of it? My filter was somehow ignored by QueryProvider translator? optimizer? What is the performance overhead of casting to IEnumerable and back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried several different approaches and I finally I have found a part of my code not tested yet. It turned out that LINQ Queries to NHibernate caused some issues when using Where clause, that I have not noticed before.

Eventually, I figured out, that I am using a wrong version of LINQ to NHibernate QueryProvider (not the one included in NH 3.0) and that is a known issue. Now that I have get rid of it, everything works fine. THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP, GUYS! You pointed me out to the right direction.

Mentioned issue is described in following thread:
[Problem with linq query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940631/problem-with-linq-query)

Answer (score 5):

When you return an `IQueryable<T>`, you are not actually returning a result set.  What you are returning is *an object that can be queried.*

Execution of the `.Where()` method is *deferred* until you (or someone calling your method) actually compels execution of the Linq chain.  This is what makes it possible for downstream clients to apply their additional Linq methods to the result, *and still get lazy evaluation for the entire Linq chain.*

So when you say that the `IQueryable<T>` is returning all records, you're probably looking at the result in the debugger, and it's showing you the original data set without the filtering (since the `.Where()` hasn't executed yet).

The reason casting to `IEnumerable` works is because it *triggers execution of the Linq command chain,* and the result is a bonafide list, rather than *an object that can be queried.*  Calling `ToList()` or `ToArray()` will also trigger execution.

In short, the only way you can be sure you're seeing the correct result from your Linq methods *during your testing process* is to force execution of the Linq chain:

```
foreach(var record in GetAllActive.ToList())
{
    // Display each record
}
```

For a little flavor of how this works, see [Working with Deferred Execution](http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2010/04/19/understanding-linq-to-sql-6-working-with-deferred-execution.aspx).  It contains an example showing how you can actually get into trouble returning an `IQueryable` from a `using` block, because the `IQueryable` object gets disposed *before the query executes.*

Comment: I am aware of most of the facts you mentioned and I can understand how it works. However, obviously, the solution CodeInChaos proposed could not be accepted in production environment, as it breakes deffered execution, which is really appreciated here. I believe everybody could agree, that the expected result my code should be slightly different, as deffered execution should NOT change behavior of the query regardless of the moment it was specified or consumed.

Comment: When you eventually *consume* the query somewhere in the code (by producing a list), you *will* get the correct result. You only have to perform the cast or `ToList()` if you wish to *test* the query result prior to it being consumed in downstream code. I suggest that you perform the `ToList()` in your unit test; you don't need to return an `IEnumerable` in your `GetAllActive()` method. In fact, it defeats the purpose.

Comment: BTW. what is the difference between iterating through all elements using foreach(var record in GetAllActive) and foreach(var record in GetAllActive.ToList()). Anyway, the query has to be executed at the time of the loop execution.

For sure, in both ways you get you IQueryable from the outside of the using block.

Comment: Am I right to say that calling `GetAllActive().Count()` by a Unit Test is a right way to consume the Query? It does not return the right result anyway.

Comment: I don't think there is a difference, really.  The `foreach` acts on an IEnumerable, so it will force execution anyway.  I just included the ToList() for illustrative purposes; it makes the conversion to an IEnumerable explicit, rather than implied.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468851.aspx) says that IQueryable.Count is *"dependent on the implementation of the type of the source parameter. The expected behavior is that it counts the number of items in source."* Try `GetAllActive().AsEnumerable.Count()`.

Comment: Ok, AsXXX probably will work in any scenario, but still, it is not what you would like to use before any execution. And still, it looks like we both agree, that foreach should do the work, and it does not. Could it be a fault of NHibernate? Also debugger, when forced to execute the query should return the right result, but it does not.

Comment: `foreach` is just a state machine. Each time through a `foreach` loop, it `yield return`s one item from... some-sequence. The only way to guarantee what some-sequence is (at any given moment) is to bake the whole sequence into an `IEnumerable`. It's entirely possible for some-sequence to change in between each `yield return`.  Bottom line: It will work as expected when it is properly consumed.

Comment: GetAllActive().AsEnumerable().Count() still gives a wrong result

So far only AsEnumerable() before Where clause makes it work.